# Automatically post to Instagram from Twitter / Facebook / Tumblr post?

Tags: instagram, if-this-then-that, automation, zapier

I have a blog and various social media channels to which I regularly post a curated set of images. I'd like to automatically post to Instagram. My current multi-platform social media setup is like this:

1. Upload photos to my Dropbox folder.
2. Run an IFTTT workflow to automatically add all Dropbox photos to my Tumblr queue.
3. Run a IFTTT workflow to automatically post all new Tumblr image posts to Facebook and Twitter.

The image post to Instagram could be taken picked up from any of the above platforms at any stage in the workflow, but so far I've been unable to find a tool that will do this for me. Can this be done by using a "api linking service" like IFTTT or Zapier, etc. or a social media management tool like Hoot-suite or Buffer? Or is there any other way?

---

**Question Update Feb 2020**

I have placed a bounty on this question in order to get an updated answer, ive noticed that Instagram now seem to allow scheduled posts via some 3rd party applications like Hootsuite or Later. Now that Instagram have allowed scheduled posts, is it possible to fit a a scheduled instagram post workflow into the workflow i have explained in my original question above, either using IFTTT, Zapier or another platform ?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the Instagram API does not allow for posting to Instagram. It can only be used to get information *from* Instagram. That's why IFTTT and Zapier aren't going to be able to help you here.

Consider using Instagram as your starting point. For instance, post to Instagram and automatically also post to Tumblr.

Answer (score 0):

You can link other social media platforms to Instagram and thus post once in Instagram and the others will be updated automatically. In your Instagram account, you can link your Facebook and other accounts by choosing: Profile - Settings - Linked Accounts, then select the types of accounts you want to link from the list. And provide any credentials of course.

As the previous answer noted, Instagram allows you to pull images from their platform, but not add new images from outside platforms. You can use apps like HootSuite and Tailwind (who are both approved Instagram partners) to setup your posts and schedule them, then the app does the posting work -- I've used HootSuite and it also posts to other social media platforms. If there are additional actions you want to perform inside of Instagram, the API may help you do that programmatically.  In case you are not familiar with it, here is a link to resources and Instagram [API tutorials](https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Instagram+API) to get started.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

Zapier now supports Instagram for Business which means that you can use it to automatically publish posts on Instagram. You must first convert your account to Business (It's free and available to anyone).

For the Twitter -> Instagram workflow you can use https://pikaso.me to screenshot your tweets.

This blog post has detailed instructions on how to do it: https://pikaso.me/blog/how-to-automatically-publish-your-tweets-on-instagram